# Why is my Eclipse CWD in this non-intuitive location?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

According to https://viralpatel.net/blogs/get-eclipse-current-workspace-path/ an easy way to find the location of your current workspace is to open the Switch Workspace dialog. The location of the current workspace should be the default path there. In my case it points to ~/Eclipse workspaces, which makes sense - it was my intention to store it there. There is also a 55 MB .metadata folder there with time stamps that makes sense.

Furthermore, when I look under Run Configurations -> Arguments -> Working Directory for my current project *Foo*, it is set to its default value `${workspace_loc:foo}`. So far so good. However, when I created a directory *ABC* in my program it ended up at ~/git/foo/ABC.

Admittedly, that is where my source is (according to the properties in Eclipse for my Main.java its path is ~/git/foo/src/main/java/io/zzzz/foo/Main.java).

I don't understand how Eclipse determines which directory it should use for CWD. Please enlighten me!

Edit: all other settings are at their default value.

Answer (score 0):

The Run Configuration value is always used when you run your program.

The variable `${workspace_loc:foo}` means the location of the **contents** of project `foo`. If your project's contents are outside of the workspace the result will be a path that is not in the workspace.

Comment: So "workspace_loc" is a quite bad name for what it actually is? It should be something like "project_dir" or so?

Comment: `workspace_loc:foo` reads quite literally "The location of `foo` in the workspace"

Comment: Originally it just meant the location of project 'foo' in the workspace, but more recently the ability to have the project contents outside of the workspace was added.